# PHPStan do not like logical if shorthand?

Tags: php, phpstan

Why does phpstan dislike the definition of foo.
That's not a wrong code, or is it? 
Although logical *if* shorthands are difficult to read and are very error-prone.

```php
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);

if(!defined('BAR')) define('BAR', 'bar');
!defined('FOO') && define('FOO', 'foo');

echo BAR;
echo FOO;
```

Test: https://3v4l.org/iuIrm 
PHPStan: https://phpstan.org/r/366b787e-53e9-4601-9770-c65c9382212e

Comment: `!defined('FOO') && define('FOO', 'foo');` doesn't seem like proper coding to me, either. It may work, but it's not very intuitive.

Comment: Is there really any need for the second version, the first is clear and is not much longer than it but is (IMHO) much clearer.. Just because code is valid, it doesn't mean it should be used.

Comment: No, there is no need for the second version. @NigelRen
Myself dislike logical abbreviations. I was just amazed that PHPStan reacts like this on level 1, although in my opinion there is no error here.
So I wanted to read the community's opinion on it.

Comment: There is a thread that is similar to this, although slightly different, here: https://giters.com/phpstan/phpstan/issues/5939